# TailwindCss + Rails troubleshooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS for a new rails app, following this guideline - `https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails`

I keep getting 404 in my networks tab when loading tailwind assets but couldn't figure out the issue

[image]

Comment: Hi there, which ruby on rails version are you using?